# Why are 3rd party recruiters claiming to submit me to a hiring manager but not doing it?

Tags: recruitment, lying

Over the last 2 months I've had multiple recruiters interview me and then claim they are going to submit me for the job we discussed, they send me an email stating "I have submitted you for x job". Then later they reach back out saying the job didn't open back up and they have a new one at a lower rate they'd like to submit me to.  I've had this happen with 3 recruiters all at different agencies.

Comment: And the answerable question is...?

Comment: We have no way of knowing why they are doing this, or even if they are doing this. We can't answer.

Comment: A recruiter may know the answer.  Of course you can't know if I'm being honest about my experience this is the internet after all, but this is happening to me and it's with different recruiters at different agencies, which leads me to believe it's likely a standard practice in the 3rd party recruiting industry

Comment: Recruiters can't read mind of unknown entitiy either. From my experience in hiring, if you weren't invited forward the answer is simple - other candidates were better. Sometimes you also got unlucky and landed in the trash pile prematurely, but most of the time it's the first column.

Comment: So 3rd party recruiters are also filtering for who they'll submit to a client?  If that's the case I guess it makes more sense to apply directly every time a 3rd party recruiter reaches out about a position

Comment: Filtering out candidates is core of the service they provide, yes. Upside is that if they are good at it, the candidates they push through get a lot more attention than they would when reached out of nowhere.

Comment: They had me on the phone once or twice a month to make sure I know what a great opportunity position x is, and that they just wanted to make sure that I am still interested in it, because they are about to submit my cv. The position being some random opening they found on Linkedin.

Comment: @WorkingHard_Guy: In other words, they wanted to discourage you from taking another job before they could hook you up and claim their finder's fee. Conflict of interest....

Answer (score 8):

I found an answer on LinkedIn from a recruiter I know. Many recruiters post fake jobs to build their network of candidates for when they have real jobs available but lie to the candidate about the current job. This seems to explain what's been happening to me that lead me to ask this question.

Comment: I wish I could say that this behavior surprises me ... but it doesn't.